# How to get FormData object and submit the form data by ajax use asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I would like to get a `form` object and submit the data to server with a button click in Asp.net MVC.

This is my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" form-sync="ajax">
  @Html.Hidden("InvtId", item.InvtId)
</form>
```

This is my JS code:

```
$(document).on("click", "[form-sync='ajax']", function() {
  var formdata = new FormData($(this).closest("form")),
    url = $(this).data("url");
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response.message);
      return false;
    },
  });
});
```

This is my MVC code:

```
var data = Request["InvtId"];
```

The problem is the `data` variable is empty

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your `form-sync` attribute is non standard so your HTML is invalid. You should make that a `data` attribute.
- You need to hook to the `submit` event of the form, not `click`.
- The `FormData` constructor expects a DOMElement, not a jQuery object as you are currently passing to it. You can just give the `this` reference as that is the DOMElement.
- The `form` has no `data-url` attribute. I assume you want the `action` property instead, which will default to the current page as you haven't provided one explicitly.
- The `return` statement in your `success` handler is redundant.
- You need to stop the standard form submission (as you're submitting via AJAX instead) by calling `preventDefault()` on the passed submit event.

Here's a complete example with all the above fixes:

```html
<form method="post" data-form-sync="ajax">
    @Html.Hidden("InvtId", item.InvtId)
</form>
```

```js
$(document).on('submit', '[data-form-sync="ajax"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: 'post',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.message);
        },
    });
})
```

Comment: Rory, thanks for the great answer but I have one question. When you say: `You *need* to hook to the submit event of the form, not click.` are you saying that it is **necessary** to do so or that it is **preferable** to do so?

Comment: @Mango necessary, otherwise you will submit the form whenever you click within the form to fill out your data

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I also added a note about using `preventDefault()` which is also required here too.

Comment: Rory there could be a possible mistake in your answer. When you use `this` inside of the `$.ajax()` argument (the object), then isn't `this` referring to the `$.ajax()` argument? Isn't that why the OP had the `url` & the `formdata` variables?

Comment: @Mango only when you use it within the scope of an anonymous function you provide to `success`/`error`/`finally`. Within the object the scope is the same as the `submit` handler, so `this` refers to the `form`.

Comment: Well, once again thanks for the in depth explanation. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing in a **jQuery** element and **NOT** a **DOM** element.
For the `FormData` to actually return what you expect, you *need* to pass in a **DOM** element to its constructor.

Here, try this instead:

```
var formdata = new FormData($(this).closest("form")[0]);
```

Another problem is that the form has no `data-url` attribute.
Use the action property instead, it will return the url of the current page if you have not given a url yourself.

Here, use this instead:

```
var url = this.action; // or $(this).prop('action');
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
< button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
onclick="saveData()">Save</button>
```

**JS Code**
Inside of function saveData()

```
var formData = new FormData();
```

get values with serializeArray

```
var formulario = $("#miFormulario").serializeArray();
```

if there are extra data or files

```
formulario.push({ "name": fileName, "value": file });
```

add information to formData

```
formulario.forEach((d) => {
    formData.append(d.name, d.value); });
```

ajax request

```
 $.ajax({        
        timeout: 0,        
     url: "/InfoController/savingInfo",        
     method: "post",        
     data: formData,    
     contentType: false,   
     processData: false,   
     success: function (result) {  //do something  }   
});
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost] public JsonResult savingInfo() {     
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
     { ... }    
     var data = Request.Form;      
     var valor1 = data["dato1"];
     return Json(true);

 }
```